# Show on hover using CSS and HTML only

Tags: html, css

How to show a child `div` when hovering anchor tag?
I want to show a `div` with class `botm` when cursor hovers anchor tag. This is the exact scheme I am using so kindly keep tags in the same order:

HTML:

```
<a> Hover me!</a>
<div class="faraz"> sdjfg 
<div class="dikha">Stuff shown on hover</div>
<div class="botm"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
display: none;
}

a:hover ~ .faraz > .botm {
display: block;
background-color: RED;
height: 250px;
width: 960px;
}
.botm {
background-color: #0CC;
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent of your targeted div is hidden therefore it cannot be shown. Show the parent as well and every thing will work.

```css
a:hover ~ .faraz{
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r2Zyp/

Comment: Perfecto...THANKS i wish my reputation is atleast 15 so i can give u +

Comment: please have a look at this code
http://jsfiddle.net/farazi482/r2Zyp/2/
i want to show menuDropDOWN class div only when i hover list items under links class div